# Access SD card from VMware player?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, sd-card

I have Ubuntu 10.04 running in a VMware player virtual machine.  How do I access the SD card reader hardware from within the VM?  I see no appropriate device under `/dev` or relevant messages with `dmesg`.

Answer (score 3):

SD card readers (either internal or external) are usually connected via USB buses.
So, all you need to do is redirect the appropriate USB device to the VMware guest.

AFAIR the default settings for desktop VMware products provide for automatic USB device connection to a guest provided the guest in question has focus. If the reader does not appear in the guest Ubuntu when you insert the card while the guest is in fullscreen please check the USB virtual device settings of the guest.

Comment: I didn't really see any settings for the USB controller that are relevant.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: As for adding USB devices - here's a quote from another answer on superuser:

"Virtual Machine Menu->Virtual Machine Settings

If you don't see "USB Controller" in the list, power down the virtual machine's guest operating system. Click "Add" at the bottom of the Virtual Machine Settings window, click "USB Controller" in the list, click "Next" and click "Finish."

Then ensure it's connected to the guest and not the host:

Virtual Machine Menu->Removable Devices->->Connect (Disconnect from Host)""

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to add a hard drive (choose physical and whole disk)
Drive 0 is the hard drive in your system
Drive 1 in my case was the SD Card
There was a Drive 2 option which didn't work, so I think it was just a placeholder of some sort.

Comment: This answer worked for me too! Host system: windows 7 guest system: debian 7. See under windows computer management > storage > disk management. There you'll see your sd card listed as Drive n. Add a new hard disk to your VM as physical disk and select the Drive n. Reboot your VM and you should see the partitions of your sd card